# c++11 how to insert simple memory barrier?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I want to insert simple memory barrier, i.e. analog of C# `Thread.MemoryBarrier();`.
How can I do this on *C++*? :

This is my code to modify:

```
volatile uint32_t curWriteNum;

void ObtainAndCommit(T* val) {
    memcpy(&storage[curWriteNum & MASK], val, sizeof(T));
     // Ensure storage is written before mask is incremented
     // insert memory barrier
     ++curWriteNum;
}
```

**Update**

When I posted this question I just wanted to know how to insert memory barrier. But it seems now we discussing how to make my program valid so I adding link to full listing of the class [one reader / one writer no-memory-allocation lock-free ring-buffer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38815/one-reader-one-writer-no-memory-allocation-lock-free-ring-buffer).

Comment: Elaborate on "before". memcpy()'s side effect is already *sequenced-before* the increment's side-effect in this thread. Is `curWriteNum` atomic?

Comment: @Cubbi `volatile uint32_t curWriteNum;`

Comment: If you really want a barrier, you can use [std::atomic_thread_fence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence). But it's better to stick with `std::atomic`...

Comment: @javapowered remove `volatile`, it does exactly nothing in this case. Use `std::atomic<uint32_t>`.

Comment: why `volatile` do nothing? isn't using std::atomic "overkill"? isn't just memory barrier is enough?

Comment: @javapowered `volatile` in C++ does not provide atomicity, synchronization, or memory ordering.

Comment: @javapowered `std::atomic` in C++ is what `volatile` is in Java (well not really, but close enough). `volatile` in vanilla C++ is a **guaranteed** sign of a bug in multi-threaded code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The increment should have release semantics, so that the effects of all preceding writes do not get reordered past the increment.

Just declare `curWriteNum` as `std::atomic<int>`. Incrementing an `std::atomic<int>` has release semantics. In fact, it has `memory_order_seq_cst` semantics, which is stronger then release. To be more precise, you need `curWriteNum.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_release)`.

On the reader side you should read the value as `int n = curWriteNum;`, or again, more precise,  `int n = curWriteNum.load(std::memory_order_acquire);`.

See [std::memory_order](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) for more details. Also, the in depth videos [C++ and Beyond 2012: Herb Sutter - atomic<> Weapons, 1 of 2](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-1-of-2).

Comment: Which works if and only if the corresponding read to `curWriteNum` has acquire semantics. Release by itself is quite meaningless.

Comment: @ComicSansMS Conveniently enough, a read of a `std::atomic<int>` has acquire semantics by default (technically `std::atomic` has sequentially consistent semantics by default, which is stronger than acquire/release).

Comment: @ComicSansMS Regardless of the reader, a release semantics operation prevents reordering of the preceding writes past the release semantics operation.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin Yes, but for this to become visible in another thread you still need the acquire there. A relaxed load could still result in an unwanted race here.

Comment: @Casey True, which is why it's a good idea to not bother with memory orderings at all, unless it becomes absolutely necessary. I for one get a headache whenever I have to think about this stuff for longer than two minutes ;)

Comment: @ComicSansMS Agreed, I think recommending non-default memory orderings to a novice is like suggesting they learn how to juggle with chainsaws.

Comment: so I should just `curWriteNum.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_release)` on writer side and just read `curWriteNum` like that on reader side? I have exactly one thread that writes to `curWriteNum` and exactly one thread that reads `curWriteNum`

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin thanks, any difference between these two instructions? do you think this is ideal solution for the case when i have 1 writer (which never read) and one reader (which never write)? Also note I added link to full listing in the question description :)

Comment: @javapowered I suggest you watch those videos, it is hard to do a better job explaining the memory order constraints. These are suitable for your ring-buffer, however, you need to have a mechanism for the reader to wait for new items on the ring buffer when it is empty. Once you add that mechanism you may realise, that it is not so lock-free any more.